# SQL Multiple Queries - Too Heavy?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been coding a new dashboard, where I want to show various DB stats, mainly counting rows and setting the results into variables, its all working correctly, but I am a bit concerned that so many SELECT queries could become too heavy if a lot of users are entering or refreshing the page.

Appreciate your input :)

```
$tbl_players = players;

$xbox = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'XBOX360'");
$ps3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PS3'");
$pc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PC'");
$xbfa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'XBOX360' && fathread LIKE 'http%'");
$psfa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PS3' && fathread LIKE 'http%'");
$pfa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PC' && fathread LIKE 'http%'");
$xbcr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'XBOX360' && crthread LIKE 'http%'");
$pscr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PS3' && crthread LIKE 'http%'");
$pcr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'PC' && crthread LIKE 'http%'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($xbox))
    {
$cxbox = mysql_num_rows($xbox);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ps3))
    {
$cps3 = mysql_num_rows($ps3);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pc))
    {
$cpc = mysql_num_rows($pc);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($xbfa))
    {
$xboxfa = mysql_num_rows($xbfa);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($psfa))
    {
$ps3fa = mysql_num_rows($psfa);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pfa))
    {
$pcfa = mysql_num_rows($pfa);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($xbcr))
    {
$xboxcr = mysql_num_rows($xbcr);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pscr))
    {
$ps3cr = mysql_num_rows($pscr);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pcr))
    {
$pccr = mysql_num_rows($pcr);
}

$tbl_interactive = interactive;

$maximum = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM $tbl_interactive ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
while($max = mysql_fetch_array($maximum))
{
$cint = $max['ID'];
}
$xboxf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'XBOX360' && Type = 'Player' && $date < EndTime");
$xboxc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'XBOX360' && Type = 'Club' && $date < EndTime");
$ps3f = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'PS3' && Type = 'Player' && $date < EndTime");
$ps3c = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'PS3' && Type = 'Club' && $date < EndTime");
$pcf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'PC' && Type = 'Player' && $date < EndTime");
$pcc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive WHERE Console = 'PC' && Type = 'Club' && $date < EndTime");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($xboxf))
    {
$xboxfi = mysql_num_rows($xboxf);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($xboxc))
    {
$xboxci = mysql_num_rows($xboxc);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ps3f))
    {
$ps3fi = mysql_num_rows($ps3f);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ps3c))
    {
$ps3ci = mysql_num_rows($ps3c);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pcf))
    {
$pcfi = mysql_num_rows($pcf);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pcc))
    {
$pcci = mysql_num_rows($pcc);
}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Oh my. [**Please, stop using `mysql_*` functions.**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: @Dagon Maybe we should write a filter for browsers, that cuts `<span>`'s containing mysql_ :) Or we should report a feature request at meta.stackoverflow.com - they should block code with mysql_, like wrong titles with "problem", "help" or other words.

Comment: @Kamil it was discussed on meta with little(no) resolution, a handful people think they  are the internet police, and cant help posting it over and over again.

Comment: cheers guys! appreciate the feedback... Will get reading!

Comment: @Dagon If this was discussed on meta - OK, let it be. This is one of best sites ever, i think they know what are they doing. I thought about it again and... biggest argument against it is this, that I think we should not force anyone to use anything. Maybe mysqli_ is a virus and we all gonna die, and they risky users of that outdated mysql_ extension will survive :)

Sorry for this chatty comment. There is an "too chatty" option in reports, if someone don't like it - just report me to internet police :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is too many queries, way too much overhead, and too much heavy lifting to get the resultset you want.

You could get all nine of those counts from the `$tbl_players` table with a single statement, and on a single row. Those nine separate statements you have are preparing nine separate resultsets, and you're fetching all those rows in the resultset to the client just to get a count.  (Maybe there's some optimization in there somewhere, but MySQL is preparing all those rows to return to the client.) It would be much more efficient to have MySQL just return the counts you want, using a statement something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(p.Console = 'XBOX360' ,1,0))                             AS xbox
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PS3'     ,1,0))                             AS ps3
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PC'      ,1,0))                             AS pc
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'XBOX360' AND p.fathread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS xbfa
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PS3'     AND p.fathread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS psfa
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PC'      AND p.fathread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS pfa
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'XBOX360' AND p.crthread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS xbfr
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PS3'     AND p.crthread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS pscr
     , SUM(IF(p.Console = 'PC'      AND p.crthread LIKE 'http%' ,1,0)) AS pcr
  FROM $tbl_players p
```

That gets you back a single row, with nine values.  That would cut down on the amount of code you've got considerably, and significantly improve performance.

Similarly, you can get all those counts from the `$tbl_interactive` table with a single statement as well:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.Console = 'XBOX360' AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)) AS xbfi
     , SUM(IF(t.Console = 'XBOX360' AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)) AS xbci
     , SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PS3'     AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)) AS psfi
     , SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PS3'     AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)) AS psci
     , SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PC'      AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)) AS pcfi
     , SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PC'      AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)) AS pcci
  FROM $tbl_interactive t
 WHERE t.Console IN ('XBOX360','PS3','PC')
   AND t.Type IN ('Player','Club')
   AND $date < t.EndTime
```

---

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tbl_interactive_counts))
{
    $xboxfi = $row["xbfi"];
    $xboxci = $row["xbci"];
    $ps3fi  = $row["psfi"];
    $ps3ci  = $row["psci"];
    $pcfi   = $row["pcfi"];
    $pcci   = $row["pcci"];
}
```

---

### FOLLOWUP:

It's possible that the SQL statements above to return a `NULL` rather than a zero, when there are no rows that satisfy the predicates (that is, match the WHERE clause). To have the statement return a count of zero in place of the NULL, we can use the MySQL `IFNULL()` function as convenient shorthand:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'XBOX360' AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)),0) AS xbfi
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'XBOX360' AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)),0) AS xbci
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PS3'     AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)),0) AS psfi
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PS3'     AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)),0) AS psci
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PC'      AND t.Type = 'Player' ,1,0)),0) AS pcfi
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.Console = 'PC'      AND t.Type = 'Club'   ,1,0)),0) AS pcci
  FROM $tbl_interactive t
 WHERE t.Console IN ('XBOX360','PS3','PC')
   AND t.Type IN ('Player','Club')
   AND $date < t.EndTime
```

Note that we've just wrapped an expression:  `IFNULL(expr,0)`

That's just a shorthand equivalent to:  `IF(expr IS NULL, 0, expr)`

also equivalent to the ANSI standard:  `CASE WHEN expr IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE expr END`

(Using `IFNULL`, we only have to specify `expr` one time.)

---

Or, you could let MySQL return the NULL, and handle the replacment of the NULL with a zero in PHP.  (Note that fetched value in the `$row` array will still contain the `NULL`, but a zero will be assigned to the scalar:

```
$xboxfi = is_null($row["xbfi"]) ? 0 : $row["xbfi"] ;
```

Comment: Interesting and thanks very much for that.. I'm glad I asked !! :)

Comment: @Kelley Lewis: I'm glad you found something there interesting. I might note that you may not notice much of a difference in the elapsed time for a single page load.  The efficiency aspect really comes to a head when the server is under load, when the issue is scalability... not necessarily how fast is a single page load, but rather, how many page loads can we do in a given timeframe.

Comment: I've been editing, manipulating cms/forum systems for years, so my experience is really messing with code that already exists.. more recently I have been working on my own application, using the knowledge i have gained in the process, but this is certainly an eye opener.. I want to get it right, i understand that everyone will have there own right or wrong way of doing things and its evident that I was right to ask the question! its all part of the learning process I guess!

Comment: Thanks again.. I tried this out and was very pleased with the results.. !

Comment: Just a quick one.. I have noticed that if all statements return 0 rows then the output for every variable is ""  However if a single row is returned from any of the statements, then all variables are populated with a 0 with the exception of the returned answer which is correct.. This is for the Interactive Counts... how could I ensure that a 0 is displayed if no rows are returned .. thanks

Comment: @Kelley Lewis: followup added to my answer. Yes, it's possible for the `SUM()` expression to return a `NULL` (in this case, when there are no rows that match the predicates in the WHERE clause.) But those queries will return a single row. It's easy to have the statement return a zero instead of a NULL, the MySQL `IFNULL()` function is a shorthand convenience for doing just that.

Comment: Thanks very much.. that looks so much better!

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure you have proper indices (indexes if you prefer) in place.

Also you might want to use COUNT instead of selecting lots of rows and then using only the row count. This is because a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'XBOX360'
```

... is sending back lots of data, and since you're not using it, that's wasted bandwidth and unnecessary extra loading time. Better go with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_players WHERE Console = 'XBOX360'
```

...and then put the proper PHP in place to retrieve only the count.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending 9 requests to the server which requires 9 round trips. Why not just use a single `UNION ALL` and a single request? Not knowing enough about your program, it's safe to say you may want to consider some redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have in your table, you may be able to use an aggregate query to get the information you need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `total`, Console, fathread 
FROM $tbl_players
GROUP BY Console, fathread
```

Comment: @Barmar I have no idea, it is a colmun in the original question.

Comment: fathread is a column with a stored URL.. I'm counting how many times its been filled in ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just counting the number of entries in each category, you could eliminate most of the queries by using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`. An example:

```
$tbl_players_result = mysql_query("SELECT Console, COUNT(*) AS item_count FROM $tbl_players GROUP BY Console");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tbl_players_result))
{
    /* Testing... */
    print($row["Console"] . " - " . $row["item_count"] . " items");
}
```

You can do the same thing for the queries with additional conditions (fathread, crthread).

Also, you only need to call `mysql_num_rows` once per result, so you don't need those `while` loops either.

Answer (score 0):

Many CMS systems and online shops run 50 or more queries at one refresh.

Anyway - in your case - I see some optimization possibilities. For example - you can read information about many types and consoles in one query, then do some work on processing/filtering returned data in PHP. Maybe you should make some easy and medium exercises in PHP (arrays, result fetching, foreach loops) and a little MySQL training. It will help you a lot. I think most time-efficient educational materials are at [The New Boston](http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php) or [PHP Academy](https://phpacademy.org/learn). There are many valuable video tutorials.

I will not give you complete solution (it could take too much time), Im not sure what is final purpose of your queries, but you may start with consolidating them into one query.

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_interactive 
WHERE 
    Console IN('XBOX360', 'PS3', 'PC') && 
    Type in('Player','Club') && 
    $date < EndTime
```

If you want to get only number of rows - you should not use `*` and count resultset rows count in PHP.

Use one field or count(*) function. Adding `GROUP BY` on some fields, and adding these fields to result (after or before count) will divide your count results into few rows containing few options, and counts of rows mathing your groups.

Count and group by example:

```
SELECT Type, Console, count(*) FROM $tbl_interactive 
WHERE 
    Console IN('XBOX360', 'PS3', 'PC') && 
    Type in('Player','Club') && 
    $date < EndTime
GROUP BY Type, Console
```

of course you have to read resultset, not number of returned rows.

Try it in MySQL workbench or phpmyadmin to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks Kamil.. Its about reporting the numbers of affected rows defined by the statements.. e.g Show How many Players play xbox or PS3 who have also decided to add a URL in the same record.. this sits on a dashboard.. the user can select to "Drill down" and see those affected rows on a new page..